# Making background thread to wait until another background thread gets completed in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, multithreading, background-process

How to make a backgroundthread not to work until another background thread gets completed and how to make it to start it's thread once the first backgroundthread gets completed

Comment: kindle please help me out if u know the answer

Comment: I have written some code use it. For more help you should show some code here so i can understand the scenario...enjoy..

Comment: Probably need to use Serial Dispatch Queue.  https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW1

Answer (score 2):

Use flag to handle such type of event as shown below...

```
BOOL isYourthreadexecuting = NO;

- (void)beginThread {   
    isYourthreadexecuting = YES;

    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(backgroundThread) withObject:nil];
}
- (void)backgroundThread {
    [myClass performLongTask];

    // Done!
    isYourthreadexecuting = NO;
}
- (void)waitForThread {
    if (! isYourthreadexecuting) {
        // Thread completed
        [self callyourmethod];
    }
}
```

**Edited >> Addition according use comment**

I suggest you to use [NSOperationQueue](http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/03/04/iphone-coding-turbo-charging-your-apps-with-nsoperation/) for multithreading.

Hope, this will you...

Comment: now am following the process that u mentioned in ur answer but the problem is the second background thread may start any moment and it may start from other class methods also

Comment: @user1184202 If You got your answer and it will help you then mark it correct its helpful for other and its gud for you also

Answer (score 2):

As stated in my comment, you can use GCD's Serial Dispatch Queues.  Here is a sample code to demonstrate:

```
- (IBAction)buttonSerialQ2Pressed:(id)sender 
{
    dispatch_queue_t serialdQueue;
    serialdQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.mydomain.testbed.serialQ2", NULL);
    dispatch_async(serialdQueue, ^{
        //your code here
        [self method1];
    });
    dispatch_async(serialdQueue, ^{
        //your code here
        [self method2];
    });
    dispatch_async(serialdQueue, ^{
        //your code here
        [self method2];
    });
    dispatch_async(serialdQueue, ^{
        //your code here
        [self method3];
    });
}

-(void)method1
{
    for (int i=0; i<1000; i++) 
    {
        NSLog(@"method1 i: %i", i);
    }
}

-(void)method2
{
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) 
    {
        NSLog(@"method2 i: %i", i);
    }
}

-(void)method3
{
    for (int i=0; i<100; i++) 
    {
        NSLog(@"method3 i: %i", i);
    }
}
```